# Where i can find all the error codes for [ firebase_auth: ^1.0.1 ]

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Is there any documentation available, which provides all the error codes related to `firebase_auth`.
I am using `firebase` with `flutter`, i have done my research and cannot find any good source where i can find all the error codes for `flutter`.

For eg:
On password error the code is wrong-password

```
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {

      //i am talking specifically about this code
      return e.code;

    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      return 0;
    }
```

Though, i have found this file where all the errors are present inside comment. https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/6bd6cd84a624a533857105e30f85650c5c68a2f7/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/firebase_auth.dart#L426

But cannot find any rigid documentation available for `firebase_auth: ^1.0.1` which states all the errors.

Thanks

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors

Comment: Thanks @thenoobslayer, but these are for JS and does not supports flutter entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter introduces its own layer on top of firebase Auth and simply routes Firebase Errors through it. You can find a list of error codes below.

Unfortunately, Flutter currently does not maintain a list of active error codes but rather attempting to catch all errors with the same handler.

Here is a list of error codes I could find

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/error-handling

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Enums/AuthErrorCode

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors

https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Handling_Firebase_Authentication_Errors_and_Failures#FirebaseAuth_Error_Codes

If you are experiencing specific errors, feel free to ask in another question.